# How to order the fields getting aggregated by XMLAGG function?

Tags: sql, xml

I have the below table:

```
Part_number   seq_nbr    Super_narrative
1                1        When replacing
1                2        part  with following parts
1                3        note:follwing are now available
1                4        with the organization
```

I am using the XMLAGG to aggregate the super_narrative in 1 line corresponding to part_number.

```
SELECT serv_part_nbr, rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, Super_narrative || ', ')).extract ('//text()'), ',') PHRASE_TEXT 
FROM BL_MACS_SUPERSEDENCE_NOTE
GROUP BY part_number
```

But I want to aggregate the `super_narrative` according to `seq_nbr`.

How to do that??

Answer (score 13):

You don't mention DBMS, but a wild guess would be:

```
SELECT serv_part_nbr
              , rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement(e, Super_narrative || ', ') order by seq_nbr ).extract ('//text()'), ','
                          ) PHRASE_TEXT 
 FROM BL_MACS_SUPERSEDENCE_NOTE
 GROUP BY part_number
```